# Как можно исправить ошибку No module named 'django_jinja'?

Tags: ubuntu, django, docker, pip, jinja2

> ```
> from django_jinja.builtins import DEFAULT_EXTENSIONS
> backend_1   | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_jinja'
> ```

Я pip и последней версии ставил и ниже версию пробовал, и пробовал так устанавливать:

```
pip install --user django_jinja
pip install --user Jinja2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Dockerfile убедиться, что устанавливается pip версии **18.0**, строка должна быть типа такой:

```
RUN pip install --upgrade pip==18.0
```

Если используете pip и установку с requirements, то дальнейшие шаги Вам не нужны. Просто запускаете докер и, скорее всего, он сам все установит.

Для тех кто использует Pipenv:

Запускаем контейнер, ждем пока установится pip нашей версии(**18.0**) и контейнер запустится.

Далее используем docker-compose: `docker-compose run --rm backend pipenv lock`.

P.S. Если нет docker-compose: `docker exec -it $name$_backend_1 pipenv lock`.

Ждем, пока зависимости залочатся, запускаем контейнер.